# Matrix date field error for v2.5.10 bug and fix (at least we think so)

Tags: matrix

We found an error with Matrix v2.5.10 and EE v2.5.0. Specifically the date field was throwing an error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method EE_Localize::format_date() in /chroot/home/giagingo/giaging.org/html/zIyzybo7i9Yn5T/expressionengine/third_party/matrix/celltypes/date.php on line 139
```

Answer (score 1):

line 139 of date.php is

```
$data = $this->EE->localize->format_date($params['format'], $data);
```

Looking at older versions of date.php we tried changing line 139 to read

```
$data = $this->EE->localize->decode_date($params['format'], $data);
```

And it worked!

Comment: Glad you got it fixed. The localization class was changed pretty dramatically in 2.6, so it's likely that Matrix didn't retain backwards compatibility past that update.